# Android Javascript Interface

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have a webview with a **javascript method**
that calls the android **Javascript Interface(JAVA) method** and in turn the 
Javscript Interface(JAVA) calls the **context(Reader) activity's method** to open a UI screen. 

When I run openDiscussionsUI() directly from the ReaderActivity it opens the UI fine but not when it is run from the Javascript Interface, it seems it does not completely run through the openDiscussionsUI() method as if it was **interrupted?** Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

javascript method

```
marginIconClick: function (itemId) {
    activity.startDiscussionsActivity();
}
```

(JAVA) JavaScript Interface Method

```
public void startDiscussionsActivity() {
    readerActivity.openDiscussionsUI();
    Log.e("startDiscussionsActivity","startDiscussionsActivity");
}
```

ReaderActivity method

```
public void openDiscussionsUI() {
    Log.e("openDiscussionsUI 1","openDiscussionsUI 1");
    discussionBox.startAnimation(slidenotesup);
    Log.e("openDiscussionsUI 2","openDiscussionsUI 2");
    discussionBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.e("openDiscussionsUI 3","openDiscussionsUI 3");
    discussionDescription.requestFocus();
    Log.e("openDiscussionsUI 4","openDiscussionsUI 4");
}
```

This is my log

Click on icon number #1

```
11-06 17:21:39.190  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 1﹕ openDiscussionsUI 1
11-06 17:21:39.190  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 2﹕ openDiscussionsUI 2
```

Click on icon number #2

```
11-06 17:22:32.154  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 1﹕ openDiscussionsUI 1
11-06 17:22:32.154  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 2﹕ openDiscussionsUI 2
11-06 17:22:32.154  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 3﹕ openDiscussionsUI 3
11-06 17:22:32.170  12951-12951/com.double_eye.monamiq I/WEBVIEW﹕ Message - 266:Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

Click on icon number #3

```
11-06 17:22:52.818  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 1﹕ openDiscussionsUI 1
11-06 17:22:52.818  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 2﹕ openDiscussionsUI 2
11-06 17:22:52.818  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 3﹕ openDiscussionsUI 3
11-06 17:22:52.818  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 4﹕ openDiscussionsUI 4
11-06 17:22:52.818  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/startDiscussionsActivity﹕ startDiscussionsActivity
```

Click on icon number #4

```
11-06 17:23:37.850  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 1﹕ openDiscussionsUI 1
11-06 17:23:37.850  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 2﹕ openDiscussionsUI 2
11-06 17:23:37.850  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 3﹕ openDiscussionsUI 3
11-06 17:23:37.850  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/openDiscussionsUI 4﹕ openDiscussionsUI 4
11-06 17:23:37.850  12951-12980/com.double_eye.monamiq E/startDiscussionsActivity﹕ startDiscussionsActivity
```

By the 3rd and 4th time it runs through but still does not show the ui, very strange.

### Update:

The callbacks from Javascriptinterface did not run on UI thread

public void test() {
        // Arrives here in 1ms after calling AndroidInterface.test(). Arrives n the web thread.

```
public void startDiscussionsActivity() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                readerActivity.openDiscussionsUI();
                Log.e("startDiscussionsActivity","startDiscussionsActivity");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you are running openDiscussionsUI() on the main thread.  I seem to remember that JavaScript Interface callbacks are spawned on a separate thread however I can't verify it right now.

Comment: Looks like this was the problem that the callback did not run on ui thread, have added fix to awnser, thanks for the help man :D

Comment: Your welcome.  I have posted as an answer, if you would select it I would be much appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure any ui work is performed on the main (UI) thread.  The JavaScript Interface calls back on to a separate thread meaning that you will need to call myActivity.runOnUiThread() or a similar function.